# 返り値の設定方法が分かりません。

Tags: php, cakephp

ビューファイルに入力され、Postされた値をControllerファイルの `$id` に入れたいのですが、恥ずかしながら返り値の書き方が分からず、質問させて頂いてます。
この `$id` にフォームに入力された値を入れたいです。

＜やりたい事＞
ビューファイル＝個人情報変更フォーム入力　→　個人情報更新

```
public function profile()
    {
        $this->request->data('username');
        $this->request->data('pass');
        $this->request->data('email');
        ///return　

        if (!$id) 
        {
           throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
        }
        $user = $this->Post->findById($id);
        if(!$user)
        {
           throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
        }
        if($this->request->is(array('post','put')))
        {
            $this->post->id = $id;
            if($this->post->save($this->request->data))
            {
                $this->Flash->seccess(__('Your information could be updated'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action'=>'edit'));
            }
                $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to update your information'));
        }
        if(!$this->request->data)
        {
            $this->request->data = $post;
        }
      }
```

**ビューファイル**

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('users',array('action'=>'profile'));
echo $this->Form->input('username',['username']);
echo $this->Form->input('pass',['password']);
echo $this->Form->input('email',['email']);
echo $this->Form->end('Save');  
?>
```

**UserModel ファイル**

```
class User extends AppModel {
    public function getActivationHash() 
    {
        if (!isset($this->id)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return Security::hash($this->field('modified'), 'md5', true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/192996

Comment: `$id` に入れたいのはフォームのどの値でしょうか。 `username `, `pass`, `email` しか、フォームにはフィールドとして定義されていません。

Comment: はい。username,pass,emailの値が入れたいです。

Comment: username,pass,email をまとめて、$id にセットしたいということですか。変数名が適切でないのと、その後の変数を使う処理がおかしいことになるのですがそれは無視して回答します。

Comment: 質問する場合はフレームワークのバージョンも記載してください。バージョンにより書き方が異なるので、違うバージョンでは適切ではない回答が付いてしまいます。

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP 2.x として回答します。

FormHelperによって、生成されるフィールドは `FormHelper::create` の第一引数（この場合、`users`）に準じたname属性が付与されます。

この質問のコードの場合、以下のようなinputタグがレンダリングされます。
（簡略化のためinputタグとname属性のみを記します。

```
<input name="data[users][username]">
<input name="data[users][pass]">
<input name="data[users][email]">
```

これによりPOSTされるデータは以下のような構造となります。

```
[
    'users' => [
        'username' => '...',
        'pass' => '...',
        'email' => '...',
    ],
]
```

これをコントローラー側で取り出すには、requestの`data`メソッドを使用します。

```
$data = $this->request->data('users');
// $data は、次のようなデータ構造 ['username' => '...', 'pass' => '...', 'email' => '...',]

$email = $this->request->data('users.email');
// $email は、フォームのemailの入力値
```

参考:
POST データにアクセス | リクエストとレスポンスオブジェクト - 2.x
https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/ja/controllers/request-response.html#post

補足として、ビューファイルにおいて、 `$this->Form->create('users')` としていますが、これはCakePHP 2.xの規約から外れた指定です。
規約に添うのであれば、（保存先はおそらくUserモデルでしょうから） `$this->Form->create('User')` とするべきです。
この場合、Post値の取り出しは以下のようになります。

```
$data = $this->request->data('User');
$email = $this->request->data('User.email');
```

Comment: こちらも参考に FormHelper - 2.x https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/ja/core-libraries/helpers/form.html

Comment: とても分かりやすいご説明ありがとうございます。本来ならばcookbookで自力に理解しなければいけないのでしょうが、上記のように例としてコードを頂けれるととても助かります。再度試してみます。

Comment: 一点質問があるのですが、username、passに関しては$dataで値を取るのに対して、emialのみ$emailと別で変数を設定しなければいけない理由は何故なのでしょうか？

Comment: $data=$this->request->data('User');
$email=$this->request->data('User.email');変数の定義として、Postされた値を受け取るよう上記のように記載した所、Invalid userというエラーが出現しました。

Comment: 上のコメントに書いた "その後の変数を使う処理がおかしいことになるのですが" の事象ですね。コントローラーの処理を1行1行何をしているのかコメントを入れつつ解読してみるとよいと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。 echo を入れてデバックしてみたのですが、$userの方からの返答がなかったので、こちらもコード変える必要があるという事ですね。他にも修正してみたいと思います。